# The variable animacao of Controles has not been assigned

Tags: javascript, unity3d, unity-5

Estou tentando fazer meu personagem Andar em uma animation e ficar parado na outra.

Em `Animator`, criei um parâmetro do tipo `float` **andar** para fazer o controle de troca entre as animações como mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

E atribui nas setas as seguintes condições:

*andar > 0.1 vai pra personagem;
  *andar < 0.1 vai pra personagemStop;

Exemplo de uma das setas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Meu código está desta forma:

```
#pragma strict

var speed : float;
var personagem : GameObject;
var animacao : Animator;


function Start () {
    speed = 2;
}


function Update () {
    transform.position.x += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    //O ERRO OCORRE AQUI!!!!!_________________________________________
    animacao.SetFloat("andar",Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")));
    //________________________________________________________________

    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0){
        personagem.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = Vector2(0,180);
    }
    else if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0){
        personagem.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = Vector2(0,0);
    }
}
```

---

Talvez possa ser algo relacionado a versão do Unity mas não sei o que possa ser, estou fazendo este game seguindo este tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuqGIB8j7E
Meu Unity é 5.3.1f1 e o do tutorial é 4.3.2f1

No `Animator` do exemplo, não existe o Entry mostrado na primeira imagem.

---

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable animacao of Controles has
>   not been assigned. You probably need to assign the animacao variable
>   of the Controles script in the inspector.
>   UnityEngine.Animator.SetFloat (System.String name, Single value)
>   Controles.Update () (at Assets/Assets/Scripts/Controles.js:17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei o problema.

No link do tutorial mencionado na pergunta, em aproximadamente 5:28 do vídeo ocorre um erro, dai vem uma tela preta dizendo que foi resolvido mas não explica exatamente o que aconteceu.

De fato, ele esqueceu de mostrar uma coisa, no objeto quando adicionamos o código javaScript a ele, devemos informar o `personagem` e a `animação` como mostra na imagem. Se não fizer isso, ocorre o erro mencionado na pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Animacao - **personagem (Animator)** é o `Animator` da primeira imagem da pergunta.
Personagem - **personagem** é filho de principal, onde ocorrem as trocas de sprites.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]